# Redundant occurances of a statically linked library?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, build, linker, dependencies

First, we have a `system` project, which provides some abstract architecture classes. Then, several `module` projects with different names inherit from one of system's classes to implement specialized features. Last, an `application` brings both together. It instantiates the base architecture from system and attaches modules to it.

This gives the following dependencies.

- `system` has no dependencies and builds to a static library.
- All `module`s depend on `system` and build to static libraries.
- `application` depends on `system` and on all `module`s and builds the executable.

When I build this setup, do all `module` libraries contain copies of the `system` library? If so, can I prevent this behavior? In the end, they are, anyway, statically linked together in the executable along with the `system` library.

Comment: this is not an answer, because I am not sure myself, but I would have thought that, when you link application, you would only have to link to modules.lib and this would imply that all system functions are there as well.

Comment: you could build a system as a lib and modules as dll then dynamically link to this dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build a library, nothing gets linked. A library is just a bunch of object files stuck together in an archive. It's only when you build an application that the linker gets involved, pulling in the pieces that are needed by the various components of the application.